# Removing commas and keep getting an "Error in View : 'names' attribute [17] must be the same length as the vector [1]

Tags: r

I'm trying to remove the commas from a dataset using the

```
gsub(',', '', ca_data$Income)
```

Every time I run the command, I get:

```
Error in View : 'names' attribute [17] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

and then the dataset is removed from my environment. The data set looks like:

```
Income <- c(50,000, 60,000, 70,000)
Region <- c("North", "South", "East")
df <- data.frame(Income, Region)
```

What do I need to modify to a) keep the dataset in my environment and b) remove the commas?

Comment: Your `Income` variable has no commas to remove and has more elements that `Region`. Is this intended?

Comment: If you run the three lines of code you provided, the values of the income column are 50,0,60,0,70,0. You don't use commas for numeric input in R.  The comma separates the elements so your input is being read as 50, 000, 60, 000, 70, and 000. The region column (length 3) is recycled to match the length of the income vector (length 6). The only way to have the commas in the cell entries is to have everything as a character string i.e. `c("50,000", "60,000", "70,000")` but it's not clear why you'd want to do this.